# Is there a format string parser for NSString?

Tags: iphone, cocoa, parsing, nsstring

I'd like to parse strings using format strings as in `+stringWithFormat:…`. It would be quite convenient to print and parse strings with the same format string. Only one localized would be needed.

Example:

```
NSString *format = @"His name is \"%@\"";
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:format, @"Bob"];
NSArray *array = [string parseWithFormat:format];
```

`array` should return `@[@"Bob"]`. Is there such an open source project that tries to accomplish that? I think it should be possible to convert such format strings into regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

`stringWithFormat` is "just" a front-end to `sprintf`; as it's plain C, `scanf` and its variants are also available if you need.

Comment: good recommendation. It's not trivial though to adopt to Cocoa because there's `%@` as well.

Comment: Transform all your NSStrings to C strings, and you're good to go.

Answer (score 0):

The way you describe your `parseWithFormat` function, it cannot work because of structural ambiguity.

The `%@` marker for the format substitution is gone in your result string `string`, thus the resulting extraction can be ambiguous.

*Example*:

```
NSString *format = @"He likes %@ and %@.";
NSString *string = [NSString 
   stringWithFormat:format, @"apples and oranges", @"bananas"];
// --> @"He likes apples and oranges and bananas."
NSArray *array = [string parseWithFormat:format];
// Array could be:
// @[@"apples and oranges", @"bananas"] or 
// @[@"apples"  @"oranges and bananas"]
```

Comment: Parsers always have to deal with ambiguities. That's also the case for regexes. I'd be fine with that.